# Match every character but backreference in JS

Tags: javascript, regex, backreference

I'm struggling with a regular expression to catch `Anything` in `__ 'Anything'` and in `__ "Anything"` as well.

So far, I've tried something like this `__\s*(['"])([^']+)\1` but it won't work with the second example.

I'm actually trying to do something like `[^\1]` to match everything BUT the first backreference, but that wouldn't work.

Comment: Is `Anything` always between quotes, be it single or double ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) to emulate a negated character class with multicharacter alternatives:

```
__\s*(['"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE9hW7/1)

If there can be a newline in between the quotes, replace `.` with a `[\s\S]`:

```
__\s*(['"])((?:(?!\1)[\s\S])*)\1
```

Here is a working snippet:

```js
var re = /__\s*(['"])((?:(?!\1).)*)\1/g; 
var str = '__ \'Anything1\' and in __ "Anything2"';

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   document.body.innerHTML += m[2] + "<br/>"; // demo
}
```

As per Sebastian Proske's comment, it is certainly possible to use alternation here:

```
__\s*(?:'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")
```

Just the values will be in separate groups, and backtracking will still be present.

```js
var re = /__\s*(?:'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")/g; 
var str = '__ \'Anything1\' and in __ "Anything2"';
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  document.body.innerHTML += (m[2] ? m[2] : m[1]) + "<br/>"; // demo
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier (and a bit quicker) to just use an alternation like `__\s*(?:'([^']*)'|"([^"]*)")` for this special case - not needing backreferences at all. Anyways +1 for the backreference solution and explanation.

Comment: @Sebastian: It is surely possible to use alternation. The values will be in different groups though. As for performance, it all depends on the input text quality and length.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work with backslashes? So that `__ 'You can\'t create a new user'` would match `You can't create a new user`

Comment: Yes, it is easy. The regex will look like `/'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'/g`.